# Query in Yii - Adding Condition

Tags: php, sql, yii

I want to add a condition to my query, which will remove the `product_id` that is equal to `999`. Currently, I get the following error: `Property "CDbCriteria.where" is not defined.` Any suggestions?

**Query in my PHP Controller**

```
$products = Product::model()->findAll(array(
                    "condition" => $condition,
                    "where" => 'product_id != 999',
                    'order' => 'product_name ASC'
                ));
```

**Updated Code**
This still doesn't remove `product_id 999`, but it doesn't throw an error.

```
$products = Product::model()->findAll(array(
                        "condition" => $condition + 'where product_id != 999',
                        'order' => 'product_name ASC'
                    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original code wouldn't work because I was passing an array of `CDbCriteria`. It also doesn't allow the `where` statement. I ended up concatenating my condition with `$condition` using the `.` and changed my `where` to an `AND` statement

This is my final output:

```
$products = Product::model()->findAll(array(
            "condition" => $condition . ' AND product_id != 999',
            'order' => 'product_name ASC'
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are doing here is passing an array of CDbCriteria. Now [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) shows that CDbCriteria does not have property named "`where`". You can use `where` in your $condition by using concatenation.

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE product_id = 999
```

Only CDbCommand has property `where`

Comment: Hi @Rafay Zia Mir thanks for your answer. This is what I have now:

`"condition" => $condition + 'where id != 999',
                    'order' => 'alt_name ASC'` and it still doesn't work. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't want to `delete 999`, I just don't want to display it.

Comment: thats just an example I have provided. I answered your question about "where"

Comment: I tried the concat thing like this `"condition" => $condition + 'where id != 999', 'order' => 'alt_name ASC'` but still doesn't work. Is this the right approach?

Comment: in your question you are saying "which will remove the product_id that is equal to 999" but in your code you are writing "id != 999" that means id is not equal to 999

Comment: Okay, just made that change, but still nothing. Its pretty weird.